# Renaming specific objects with bpy

Tags: python, rename, bpy

I have a custom MATLAB script that I use to analyze 3D data. I recently started using a new piece of software to export about 150 3D points over time as an .fbx file. These points (imported as individual objects into Blender) have clunky names and I want to rename about 20 of these using bpy in order to fit what my MATLAB script is expecting.

For example, I want an object called "BottomNoseBottom_99" to be called "NT" for Nose Tip. I know I can do this individually within Blender by right-clicking, but I will be doing this very often and want to create a script.

I have found a lot of references to the following piece of code, but I think (I'm new to bpy) that it only applies to an object that is currently selected:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "newName"
```

What I can't figure out is how to rename only particular objects, like this:

BottomNoseBottom_99 = "NT"

UpperLipTopCenter_65 = "CUL"

etc.

I've searched for an answer with no luck.

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Blender Python console are accessible via `bpy.data.objects` which has a `dict` interface.

Try this:

```
bpy.data.objects["BottomNoseBottom_99"].name = "NT"
```